# Laravel get next calendar date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

For example i'm getting number 25 from user, and how can i generate a complete date with Carbon or any PHP helper?

> For example today is 22 April 2015, then it will returns 25 April 2015.
>
> If today is 26 April 2015, then it will returns 25 May 2015.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Is the input "22 April 2015"?  Or is the input "25"?  Given the input what is the rule that makes the output?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically the same approach as @MarkBaker's but it uses Carbon:

```
$next = 25;

$date = Carbon::today()->day($next);
if($date->isPast()){
    $date->month++;
}

echo $date;
```

Comment: it's clean and simple! Perfect. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = 25;

$now = new DateTime();
$then = clone $now;
$then->setDate($now->format('Y'), $now->format('m'), $date);
if ($then < $now) {
    $then->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}
echo $then->format('Y-m-d');
```